# how to check an int ( not from DataBase) is null

Tags: java

such as `int a`, how can I judge `a` is null? `a` is not from DataBase.
As when the data is transferred from Internet, the value of `a` may be missing.
I need to check whether `a` is null.

-----add-----
Such As Class A has a private int a, not initial. A has a SetA() function.
May be transfer from Internet, can the A != null but A.a is not value?

Comment: A primitive int cannot be null. If you need null, use Integer instead.

Comment: Do you mean check primitive type int for null? use Integer

Comment: Your question is a bit thin, but I would recommend that your get an `Object` from your `ResultSet`.  This way, you will know if it really be `null`.  If you get a primitive `int`, then you won't be able to distinguish between `0` and `null`.

Comment: How and where do you get your `int a`?

Comment: Java `int`s default to 0 if not initialized or set.  See @Soorapadman's comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For primitive types,we have fixed memory size i.e for int we have 4 bytes and char we have 2 bytes. And null is used only for objects because there memory size is not fixed.

So by default we have,

```
   int a=0;
```

and not

```
 int a=null;
```

And Most Importantly
`int` can't be null, but `Integer` can. 
Try this

```
if(a == null){
    //try something
}
```

here the `a` instant of `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ResultSet.getObject()` to return a Java `Object` instead of working with a primitive `int`:

```
Integer val = resultSet.getObject("val") != null ? resultSet.getInt("val") : null;
```

In this case, a `null` value will really correspond to a `null` in your database table, and a value of `0` will correspond to this exact value.

Note that if you try something like this:

```
int val = resultSet.getInt("val");
if (val == 0) {
    // but 0 can mean null OR the actual value 0...
}
```

then you won't be able to distinguish a `null` value from the actual value `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Default value of primitive cannot be null. For int it should be 0.

As for data transferred from internet the value may be in string format initially. You can check if the string is null before parsing it to int.